# How to bind ToolTip content in a custom textblock styles property setter

Tags: c#, xaml, xaml-binding

I am trying to create a textblock that shows a tooltip of the textblock's text when its being trimmed.  I have the actual visibility part of this taken care of in a converter.  My problem is binding the ToolTip's content to its partent textblock's text.  I have been fiddling with different relative paths for awhile now and can never get anything but a blank tooltip.  The text shows up fine when I want if I hardcode something in the tooltips content.

```
<Style x:Key="InfoToolTipBaseTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource TrimmedVisibilityConverter}}" Content="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}}"/>                
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a tooltip that's always there, setting its content, and then switching its visibility, just have a style trigger on the TextBlock that sets the ToolTip property to Text when needed.

I've used your existing converter, but you might want to rewrite it to return `bool`. Then you'd have `Value="True"` in the `DataTrigger`.

```
<Style 
    x:Key="InfoToolTipBaseTextBlockStyle" 
    TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}"
    >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TrimmedVisibilityConverter}}"
            Value="Visible"
            >
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I don't know if this is an issue for you, but if `Text` changes at runtime, the the tooltip won't be updated, because that Binding doesn't know you care about the `Text` property. The fix for that would be to rewrite the converter as `IMultiValueConverter` so you can use it with a MultiBinding that would have bindings to `Text` as well as `Self`. It wouldn't have to *use* `Text`, but it would update the target when `Text` changes.

A better solution, simpler and WPFish, would be to write a behavior for `TextBlock` that recycles the guts of your converter, handles change notifications on Text, and updates an attached `TextBlockExt.IsTextElided` bool property on the TextBlock.

Comment: I figured it out.  I updated the converter to return a bool but not the value in the data trigger value binding.  Working fine now thanks!  Im amazed there isnt an easier native way to do this as i would think its a common problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ed .  This was bugging me.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I regret that TextBlock doesn't have a property that indicates whether the Text is currently elided. That would be in the spirit of WPF. In fact, it shouldn't be at all hard to write a behavior for TextBlock that recycles the guts of your converter, handles change notifications on Text, and updates an attached `TextBlockExt.IsTextElided` bool property on the TextBlock.

Comment: ha maybe I spoke too soon.. I could have sworn this was working before i went to lunch, but now the converter, when checking on the actual width, always has a value of zero, so it always returns true.  Fantastic disappointment :(

Comment: My first wild guess that it's being invoked just once -- on creation, before the TextBlock gets its text. I'd look at the MultiConverter/MultiBinding thing, and bind (but not use) Text so it'll update every time Text changes.

Comment: I thought that too but the framework element is showing the text having the expected value.  Not sure if it has to render first or something.  Back to tinkering.

Comment: Maybe go back to the behavior idea -- write a behavior that handles `SizeChanged` on the TextBlock. Every time the size changes it checks if it's elided and sets an `IsTextElided` attached property to true or false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162453/discussion-between-derek-meyer-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 2):

Solved it simply by this.

```
        <Style x:Key="InfoToolTipBaseTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource TrimmedVisibilityConverter}}"
                             Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Text}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```